# Master thesis topic that nobody in the department studies

Tags: phd, masters

I am trying to apply to a university for a PhD position. My master's thesis is dedicated to a topic that nobody in my department (or even in my country) studies or even has deep knowledge of. My thesis is complete and perfectly fine. It has been proofread by a third person outside the department, an expert on the subject.

With this in mind, is it a good idea to mention in the statement of purpose that this is the situation in order to highlight capabilities for independent work and motivation?

Answer (score 6):

It would probably be good to mention that your MS thesis was actually done independently of local supervision and that you are comfortable with independent research. And also that you have positive feedback from external expert(s).

This would be especially true if it is generally considered an important area of research and you want to do something adjacent to it in doctoral studies.

You don't need to spend a lot of space on it if your space is limited. Be prepared to say more in an interview.

It wouldn't be a negative in any case, even though in some places (US, particularly) it might not add a lot.